# Is there any table in order to identify device brand from MAC address?

Tags: java, php, mac-address

I heard that it's possible to identify the brand of a device (or at least the NIC brand) using part of it's MAC address. Is this possible? How would I do it? Is there a chart somewhere that lists the most common partial-MACs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup. You can find it from the IEEE: http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt

Answer (score 2):

MAC-Addresses are assigned by IEEE. Search / browse and download at http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an API around it, this is the right solution :- http://www.macvendors.com/api

High performance lookup of MAC address vendors by simple HTTP GET requests.

Hope it helps. Thanks